# Export "Identify Results"

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS there is an option to select features of a selected layer and see the results of a panel called "Identify Results".

I want to export to a text file or CSV all those selected features.

Is there any way of achieving this using Python code or a plugin ? I am sure there must be a way of getting this information.

Comment: You could select those features and export the selection.